# VS2010 final does only link project on "rebuild all", not on "build changed"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

I've just migrated a solution containing c++ and c# projects from VS2008 to VS2010 and got a strange problem.

When I select "rebuild all", everything compiles and links as I would expect it to do.

Then I change some c++ source file (just add a space), build the project, I get several **thousands of linking errors** like these:

```
GDlgPackerListe.obj : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A0000C7) ""public: bool __thiscall LList::Add(class LBString const &)" (?Add@LList@@$$FQAE_NABVLBString@@@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""public: virtual void __thiscall LRcPackerListe::HookRunReport(class LFortschritt &)" (?HookRunReport@LRcPackerListe@@$$FUAEXAAVLFortschritt@@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
Db_Lieferschein2.obj : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A0000E6) "public: bool __thiscall LList::Add(class LBString const &)" (?Add@LList@@$$FQAE_NABVLBString@@@Z).
bmed.obj : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00014D) ""public: bool __thiscall LList::Add(class LBString const &)" (?Add@LList@@$$FQAE_NABVLBString@@@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""public: virtual long __thiscall MENUKB::Methode(long,long)" (?Methode@MENUKB@@$$FUAEJJJ@Z)" verwiesen wird.
GDlgPackerListe.obj : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A0000C9) ""public: void __thiscall LList::Sort(void)" (?Sort@LList@@$$FQAEXXZ)", auf das in Funktion ""public: virtual void __thiscall LRcPackerListe::HookRunReport(class LFortschritt &)" (?HookRunReport@LRcPackerListe@@$$FUAEXAAVLFortschritt@@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
Dlg_Gutschrift.obj : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000128) "public: virtual __thiscall LBaseType::~LBaseType(void)" (??1LBaseType@@$$FUAE@XZ).
Module_Damals.lib(svSuchAltLink.obj) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall SView::SView(void)" (??0SView@@QAE@XZ)".
Module_Damals.lib(svShowEMF.obj) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual void __thiscall SView::HookValueChanged(unsigned __int64)" (?HookValueChanged@SView@@UAEX_K@Z)".
```

When I hit "rebuild all" it recompiles and links without any errors or even warnings and produces a working exe.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 final (german edition).

Whats going on here? Or, more important: how do I get the linker to work correctly??

Comment: Try deleting all intermediate files once - Start from a project folder with only source and project files in it.

Comment: Been there, tried it, but tried it again just now. Same problem: first complete rebuild does work, make afterwards fail with lots of linking errors.
And yes, I really deleted all files except source. Even the hidden ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some head scratching, we seem to have found the answer. The problems, in our case at least, were two-fold:

1. We had set up project dependencies, but weren't using the newer 'project to project' references as a means of linking projects in to the target. Seems the old dependencies dialog isn't the place to go any more.
2. We had some dubious code that had crept in where a virtual function was being defined but not implemented in a derived class - the base class had a default implementation. Why this isn't an error in rebuild all I don't know.

The following explains things better than I did :)     http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: All of this was in the comments.  I can only assume that this is really what the OP was accepting, since the original answer was a question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Yes please, that would be great.  I only took a closer look at this because it was accepted.  Otherwise I would have missed it too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: If you can edit it yourself that would be best.  If you're not sure what to do you can flag it as "Other".  If it's something that just needs deleted (like about 98% of the cases you flagged this morning) you can just flag it as "not an answer".

Comment: @Bill, alright, I'll try to follow that.  I am going to delete all my comments above (and later this one, if I remember) to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this error. My main project depends on a library and this library on another one etc. After migrating from VS2008 to VS2010, every library must be added as a reference to the main project. Now the error is gone...